# Categorical axis to Continuous ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map, where each tile is a month. If I use the dates as a data date type, I get lines over my image that are not acceptable.

[image: Heat Map with Data as Date]

So my solution has been to to treat the date as a factor

[image: Heat Map with Date as Factor]

The problem is that the axis is not presentable. Is there a way to merge the two plots with the x axis from the first plot, but the tiles from the second plot?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x    = factor(Var2),
           y    = factor(desc(Var1)),
           fill = value)) +
```

As a reproducible example:

```
df <- read.table("","Var1","Var2","value","Col"
                 "1",2001-01-31,2001-01-31,-0.0118511587908436,"blue"
                 "2",2001-02-28,2001-01-31,0,"white"
                 "3",2001-03-30,2001-01-31,0,"white"
                 "4",2001-04-30,2001-01-31,0,"white"
                 "5",2001-05-31,2001-01-31,0,"white"
                 "6",2001-06-29,2001-01-31,0,"white")

ggplot(dff, aes(x   = factor(Var2),
           y    = factor(desc(Var1)),
           fill = Col)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=pretty(p$Var2))
```

[Output from example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqNLR.png)

Comment: Can you please supply a reproducible example.

Comment: Are those lines an artifact of the bitmap representation from the R viewer pane? Try using `ggsave("test.png", dpi = 600)` and see if they're in the actual output file.

Answer (score 0):

Use dates but manually remove the grid. You can do it by adding `+ theme(panel.grid = element_blank())` to the plot.